# using local variable from one function to another

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, variables

Write a program to calculate the weekly salary of an employee using two functions. One function calculates the salary. The Other functions prints the salary. If the employee has worked overtime - his overtime pay should be time and a half. Assume there are no taxes. Write appropriate comments in code. Do not use global variables. 
this is what I have so far:

```
def payrate():
     hours = int(input('How many hours did you work?\n'))
     rate = int(input('What is your hourly rate?\n'))
     if hours <= 40:
         total = hours * rate
     else:
         total = 40 * rate + (hours - 40) * (1.5 * rate)

def salary():
     for total in payrate():
         print('Your weekly salary is $%d' %total)
         return payrate(total)
salary()
```

I know its not right but I am a beginner and learning as I go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
def payrate():
     hours = int(input('How many hours did you work?\n'))
     rate = int(input('What is your hourly rate?\n'))
     if hours <= 40:
         total = hours * rate
     else:
         total = 40 * rate + (hours - 40) * (1.5 * rate)
     return total

def salary():
     total = payrate()
     print('Your weekly salary is $%d' %total)
salary()
```

To use a "local variable" from a function - you have to return it(using the **return** keyword) like this:

```
return local_variable
```

And to receive it from another function you can call the first function inside the second function like this:

```
recieved_local_variable = first_function()
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python, you can pass arguments to functions inside of the def ... (): For example, you can pass the variables rate and hours to the function payrate that returns your calculated total:

```
def payrate(rate, hours):
    ... 
    return total
```

If you wanted a function called salary that just prints the result of the payrate function, you could do:

```
def salary(hours, rate):
   print(payrate(hours, rate))
```

The above function calls the payrate function and prints the return value.

and then simply call the salary function with the variables "hours" and "rate".

```
salary(hours, rate)
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Good job you were very close. Your salary function needs to receive the total pay from the payrate function and the payrate function needs to return the total pay to salary so it can print it. This code worked fine for me:

```
    def payrate():

      hours = int(input('How many hours did you work?\n'))
      rate = int(input('What is your hourly rate?\n'))

      if hours <= 40 :
        total = hours * rate
      else :
        total = 40 * rate + (hours - 40) * (1.5 * rate)

      return total


    def salary():
      pay = payrate()
      print('Your weekly salary is $%d' % pay)


    salary()
```

I hope this helps

Comment: thank you all for your input. this has solved my issue.